# Apex domains on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, dns

I've got a site that was originally running on a non-heroku server that I moved to heroku.  The site was using a bare domain before (`example.com`). Heroku requires non-bare domains (`www.example.com`) as per this article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains

My question is: I have a bunch of links out there currently like this: `https://example.com` which throw a browser error now that I am using non-bare domains.

This excerpt from heroku confirms the error is widespread.

`SSL
Traffic routed over SSL behaves, at the DNS level, identical to unencrypted traffic and suffers from the same naked domain limitations.
However, applications requiring SSL encryption should use the ALIAS/ANAME configuration on the root domain. Subdomain redirection will cause a browser error when the root domain is requested over SSL (i.e. https://example.com).`

How can I redirect people to the right domain without them experiencing a browser error?

EDIT:

I emailed heroku and this was their response:

`I'm afraid only the ALIAS/ANAME style records will be able to reference an SSL endpoint at the apex and from my understanding Namecheap do not support those record types. We have a few examples for various providers here. But if your domain provider doesn't support ALIAS/ANAME we can only recommend you switch to another provider that does. A URL redirector doesn't work for SSL, the CNAME type breaks email, and raw A records can break after only a few minutes.`

So I moved providers from Namecheap to Cloudflare, CNAME'd instead of redirected, and everything now works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an SSL endpoint provisioned then your visitors will get a 'certificate mismatch' error as Heroku will serve their default herokuapp.com certificate. You can't redirect https without a valid certificate as browsers first check the validity of the certificate. If you're moving to Heroku and want to respond to those requests you will need a valid certificate, SSL endpoint provisioned and a DNS provider that supports using CNAMEs on Apex records.